# Could a planet be ejected from a system by a rogue planet? (possibly in a binary pairing)

Tags: science-based, planets, space, solar-system, rogue-planets

Assuming an earth-like Solar System with an earth-like planet, **would it be possible for a rogue planet travelling at a high speed to disrupt the earth-like planet's orbit so as to leave the solar system?** The size and speed of the planet can be variable, I was picturing a larger rocky body with approximately a century of warning but a gas giant/faster moving body would work too.

As a follow up question, **would they be able to maintain an orbit around each other, like a [binary pairing of rogue planets?](https://physicsworld.com/a/pairs-of-rogue-planets-found-wandering-in-the-orion-nebula/)** In my story the setting would be on the earth-like planet orbiting around/in a pair with the other planet while ejected from the system, but the society was able to prepare for it so still exists, so I'm just wondering if this kind of setting is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A rogue body crossing the orbit of Earth would have a velocity of at least 42 km/s.

The interaction time would be short, nevertheless it could perturbate the orbit enough to end up with the expulsion of the planet from the system.

However making a bound pair would be troublesome, as 42 km/s is short of 4 times the escape velocity of Earth, thus dumping that much excess energy would be tricky.

Comment: 42-30 is less than escape velocity of Earth, so with proper speed alignment, and with some exosphere interaction, a gas giant might be able to capture Earth AND escape with it, however I believe that life on Earth won't survive the acceleration due to interaction with upper atmosphere layers of that giant. Yet I wonder if there would be a window of income velocities to allow this trick, as it would most likely involve eating up Moon, Mercury and/or Venus to alter the giant's course to be able to approach Earth slowly enough so that they might form a binary system. Needs calculations badly.

Comment: In fact, a terminal case for this question would be a black hole, that thing certainly can strip a planet off its sun's orbit, so why not an earthlike with a lighter object, if properly aligned? Yet again, needs calculations or simulations.

Comment: If a Jup-sized giant would pass at half the Moon's orbit radius with relative speed of 42 km/s, it already seems to give enough tug to Earth to fling it off the solar system, my rough calculations display about 70 km/s delta-V. Someone say a flyby maneuver, hmm. So the answer to this question's first part is a definite yes. About the second part, I believe one has to retrogradely solve a 3-body problem to determine if there would be a trajectory for a gas giant within Sun-Earth system that would cause Earth to be captured, which is IIRc impossible or at least too big to answer this.

Comment: These are all really helpful addenda, thanks! I'll see about doing my own research.